# Python measure elapsed time for code blocks using time.time()

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, time, timer

I am trying to use `time.time()` to measure the elapsed time for a code block,

```
import time
func_time_result = []
t2 = time.time()

for data in data_set:
   data_time = dict()
   t4 = time.time()
   # initialization code for running the function

   try:
      some_function(data)
   except Exception1 as e:
      exception_list.append(e)
   except Exception2 as e:
      exception_list.append(e)
   data_time.data_execution_time = time.time() - t4 # iteration execution time

   func_time_result.append(data_time)

t3 = time.time()
code_block_time_elapsed = t3-t2

time_in_total = dict()
for time in func_time_result:
   for k, v in time.items():
      time_in_total[k] += v
```

The problem is `code_block_time_elapsed` doesn't equal to the total time taken for `data_set` in `time_in_total['data_execution_time']` (e.g. `code_block_time_elapsed` is typically 210 secs and the total time taken for `data_set` is about 150 secs, so the difference is about 60 secs). I am wondering what's the possible issue?

`some_function` has something to do with inserting data into `mongoDB` using `bulk.upsert()`, `data_set` is a list that contains 7 tables, each of which has 100k rows.

Comment: What is the exact difference ("very significant" doesn't tell us much)? What's the data structure in `data_set`? Why are you storing timing information on the `time` module (in `time.data_execution_time`)?

Comment: @marcelm I have modified the OP to elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good library called [jackedCodeTimerPy](https://github.com/BebeSparkelSparkel/jackedCodeTimerPY) that works better than the time module. It also has some clever error checking so you may want to try it out.

It gives really good reports like

```
label            min          max         mean        total    run count
-------  -----------  -----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
imports  0.00283813   0.00283813   0.00283813   0.00283813             1
loop     5.96046e-06  1.50204e-05  6.71864e-06  0.000335932           50
```

I like how it gives you statistics on it and the number of times the timer is run.

It's simple to use. If i want to measure the time code takes in a for loop i just do the following:

```
from jackedCodeTimerPY import JackedTiming
JTimer = JackedTiming()

for i in range(50):
  JTimer.start('loop')  # 'loop' is the name of the timer
  doSomethingHere = 'This is really useful!'
  JTimer.stop('loop')
print(JTimer.report())  # prints the timing report
```

You can can also have multiple timers running at the same time.

```
JTimer.start('first timer')
JTimer.start('second timer')
do_something = 'amazing'
JTimer.stop('first timer')

do_something = 'else'
JTimer.stop('second timer')

print(JTimer.report())  # prints the timing report
```

There are more use example in the repo. Hope this helps.

https://github.com/BebeSparkelSparkel/jackedCodeTimerPY